# Overloading properties to ensure they are only set on first access

Tags: php, overloading, magic-methods

I have a situation where I want a class property to only be initialised if it is actually accessed, as initialising the property includes database calls which may be unnecessary. I could use a getter method but this seems like overkill, constantly calling this method (I would prefer the property to just be there as it's very frequently used 90% of the time).

So I was thinking about using PHP's [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and after a little test it appears to work fine.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Bob';
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        var_dump($this->name);
        var_dump($this->name);
        var_dump($this->name);
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        var_dump('Getting property.');

        if($property == 'name') {
            $this->name = $this->getName();
            return $this->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling doSomething() here does exactly what I want:

> string(17) "Getting property."
>
> string(3) "Bob"
>
> string(3) "Bob"
>
> string(3) "Bob"

The first time, the property is fetched via the getName() method, subsequent times the property is now set directly and can be accessed as normal.

So this does what I want. Rather than setting $this->name when the class is initialised, it sets it when it first gets accessed. I understand that the immediate response will probably be that I can just call getName() directly, but for this particular case I'd rather access via the property. The property is currently set permanently upon class initialisation, whether it is accessed or not.

EDIT: For clarification, the property is actually an Eloquent object in the real world app, NOT a string containing a name! The above was just the example I created to test that my potential solution would work correctly, and show what I am wanting to do. Additionally, there are a few of these properties. I'd rather not initialise the properties in the cases where they are not being accessed.

My question. Is this a fair use of Overloading or would it generally be frowned upon by other developers? Performance wise, is it all good, considering the overloading is only being used for the first access?

Thanks

Comment: Why are people stuck in the 90s as if our websites are all running on 386s. Is instantiating a string with a default value going to kill the server or something? We have to resort to this kind of stuff to save a few bytes of RAM like we're still on machines that only have 512k max?

Comment: So are you saying that calling a getterMethod() vs accessing a $property makes no difference on today's hardware? Even for a fairly busy web application where we are wanting the API responses to be made as quickly as possible (< 100ms from production to user, on top of Laravel). I do find accessing the property cleaner too. $this->user->id, vs e.g. $this->getUser()->id everywhere.

Comment: Your bottle neck will be on something that accesses files, like reading the session, not on accessing variables in memory. If you're really concerned with that, *don't use PHP*. Seriously, PHP is a scripting language and therefore by definition uses more memory on each request. And not only that, but associative arrays rather than just numerical indexes?  Lol. And you're worried about calling a member directly vs via a getter. Come on.

Comment: Why don't we go back to packing 5 or 6 boolean flags into one int with binary operations too while we're at it.

Comment: Your condescending and sarcastic attitude towards my question is not appreciated. People come here to ask questions and learn, not to be mocked. You have also not really answered my question. I asked for clarification on your first comment regarding property access vs method calls, whether there is any difference and at what rate (100 calls, 1000 calls, 10000 calls, etc). You responded by saying that file reads are heavier and likely to be the bottleneck, kind of obvious but not what the question asked.

Comment: Btw I just noticed in your first comment that you wrote "Is instantiating a string with a default value going to kill the server or something?". The property is an Eloquent object and involves database queries to pull it up, not a default string value! I will clarify this in my question. Additionally in the real world app there are a few of these properties holding different objects.

Comment: Yes, after you pull the value its not a default string value. But until then you want it to say "Bob" so that is. `getName() { return "Bob"; }` vs `$name = "Bob";` until something else is put into it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is known as '[lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)'. In that a member variable will only be set if it is ever called upon. Upon the first call the value is massaged, then stored, so subsequent calls do not suffer the performance hit of having to re-massage the data.

> but for this particular case I'd rather access via the property

Huh? So you'd rather do `$object->someMemberVariable` vs `$object->getValueForMember()`? Why? The latter provides you the ability to mutate the data (if necessary) in a single location, vs having to put that onus on the calling code, which could result in repeated logic, which is what you don't want. Think about a timestamp variable, instead of formatting the date everywhere you call `$object->createdAt`, you can format the date once, then make it available anywhere that needs it.

In your code snippet you are already over-engineering the `__get` call b/c you are treating it as a wrapper for the concrete accessor.

The best use of `__get` or `__set` calls are in ORMs where they don't create potentially hundreds of concrete accessors, but act as though they exist via the `__call` method.

-- Update --

You pretty much answered your own question. What you are doing here is **micro-optimization**, which has diminishing returns. But if you do as you stated

> other areas of optimisation first (database performance, file reads,
>   holding things in memory, etc))

you will get more ROI.

You could do what Alex suggested in comments, you could add a wrapper method to the user object:

```
$user->getAddress()->getStreetName();

// Becomes

$user->getStreetName();
```

While on the outset this may look optimized, it's doing the same thing, just changing the calling code a bit, for minimal gain. **HOWEVER** there are times where adding, what I call 'convenience wrappers', can add some benefit. A convenience wrapper simply wraps calls to ease the complexity of the calling code:

```
echo sprintf('%s %s %s', $user->getFirstName(), $user->getMiddleName(), $user->getLastName());

// Becomes

echo $user->getFullName();
```

Yet another **HOWEVER**, some ORMs (and frameworks) will mask the fact that they will make extra database calls to retrieve data (lazy loading). So using the above address example; even though you made a database call to return the data in the `user` table, a call to `getAddress()` will require another database call to return data in the `user_address` table. So what you can do in this instance is implement what I refer to as a **super object**, much like a regular object but only with a cape, jk. Here's what I mean:

```
// No extra DB call, as id is part of the primary table and was pulled on initial DB call
$user->getId(); 

// Even tho the ORM knows there is a relationship here it wasn't smart enough to pull it in on the initial call, so another DB call must be made
$user->getAddress()->getStreetName();

// What we want to do is incorporate our own method to retrieve a super object, so we can join all tables during initial db call and make the data available to the view

$query = 'SELECT u.*, ua.* FROM user AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN user_address AS ua WHERE u.id = 1';

// Hydrate user object accordingly
....

return $hydratedObject;
```

Now, with the super object, any calls to ancillary data stored in other tables will not cost you a DB hit, which will truly lend itself to optimizing your app.

Kind of went off on a tangent there, but in short, there is absolutely nothing wrong with calls like `$user->getAddress()->getStreetName()`. In fact, this is know as `fluent interface` and can get quite long depending upon how the classes were written:

```
$user->getCats()->getFirst()->getColor();
```

Comment: I've always been told that method calls have a hit. Given that this property is accessed a lot, that would be a lot of method calls. Is this not going to add up eventually, or is that kind of thing just way off the scale for any application, even to shave off a few milliseconds? I understand that there are other areas of optimisation first (database performance, file reads, holding things in memory, etc) but I don't want to be performing hundreds of getter method calls if it's best to access the object via a property directly (which seems to make more sense to me).

Comment: Additionally, it looks kind of nasty to me calling $this->getUser()->id, $this->getUser()->username everywhere rather than just $this->user->id, $this->user->username. I prefer things clean looking and find it easier to follow without method calls all over the show, all to access what would be best represented as a simple property to me. It's set up as a property now, I'm just looking to cancel out some database calls where the property is not even accessed in some requests.

Comment: @Mike if you are worried about calling $this->user->id, why don't you just write a method for $this->getUserId(), doesn't look messy at all and it gives you more flexibility in terms of re-use.

Comment: This help answer ur question?